# Probability to find a prime factor?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose I have been given positive numbers $n,m$, $n<m$, and an integer $N$. What is the probability that $N$ has a prime factor between $[n,m]$? I have heard about the prime number theorem but I'm not sure how can I apply it to this problem if I can apply it at all.

Comment: If $N<n$ then the probability is zero.

Comment: That depends on the distribution of $N$.

Comment: This question is not going to have a nice answer. Do you really need to pose it in such generality? There might be some hope of answering a much more restricted question, like how many 200 digit numbers are not prime but have no factors of less than 90 digits (highly relevant to cryptography).

Comment: I decided to put the question in general form to see how much we can achieve results like that. Originally I would like to know what is the probability that the general number field sieve would find a new factor to $2^{2^{12}}+1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $N$ is large compared to $m$, and $n>2$ is not too near to $m$, then the number of primes is asymptotically expected to be
$$\sum_{n\le p\le m}\frac1p\sim\log\log m-\log\log n.$$

You can treat finding a factor as a Poisson event, making your chance of finding a factor in that range approximately
$$1-\exp(-(\log\log m-\log\log n))=1-\log n/\log m.$$

Comment: This looks more like the expected number of prime factors in that range that divide N. The probability should be about $1-\prod_{n\leq p\leq m} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p} \right) $, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MichaelStocker: You're right -- I was supposing that the probability was small enough that the two are basically the same. I'll edit in the case where the probability is large.